# Build angular2 app in cli without zone.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, build, angular-cli

In my project(website) zone.js is already included in the js-bundle. On one of the pages i want to include an angular2 app which is built with the CLI.

If i do so i get the error `Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded`. It seems to be because both, the angular2 app and the js-bundle of the whole project include zone.js. So zone is loaded twice.

I can't remove zone from the project itself because it is required on every page and the angular is only include in one.

Is there a way to compile the angular2 app in the CLI without zone.js in the bundle? Or do i have to create my own build?

Additional Information on the `zone already loaded` error: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/405

Comment: I think you need to create your own build because Angular itself is dependent to Zone.JS, you cannot build it without Zone.JS, however if you already add it to your main project, you can build angular az part of main project